# What are the thoughts behind evil-move-cursor-back?

Tags: evil, vim-emulation

In Evil, there is the variable `evil-move-cursor-back`. This is what it's documentation says:

> "Whether the cursor is moved backwards when exiting Insert state."

Now, by default, it is set to `t` . The effect this has is that, if you enter Insert state and then immediately leave it (switch to Normal state), the cursor is moved back one character compared to where you started off. I understand I can change this behavior by changing the value of the variable, but as a beginner Evil and Vim user I am afraid I will not gain the benefits of having it enabled still.

So, does anyone know the background or thinking of this variable or the behavior it controls?

Comment: Sounds a bit more like a discussion opening than a specific question to solve a specific problem. This site is mainly for specific Q&A. Just what have you tried, specifically, and what problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: If I rephrase it like this: "What is the benefit of keeping `evil-move-cursor-back` set to `t`?", would it be accepted?